# How to find all Possible values for A and B, given only one equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

Given that :

$$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{12} $$

With a & b **integers**

How can I find all possible values of *a* and *b* with only one equation (this one ?) .

From what I'v learned in math classes, I need at least 2 equation to find the values of 2 variables .

Comment: What can you say about $a,b$? Do they have to be real? Rational? Integers? Positive? For example, there are infinitely many solutions for $a,b$ real, but seven for $a,b$ positive integers with $a>b$.

Comment: Sorry, I've totally forgot, They're integers, I've updated the original question ;) .

Comment: So rearranging the equation somewhat you have $(a-12)(b-12)=144$. Can you see how that might help?

Comment: But, should I use the first equation to solve it ?

Comment: The equation you gave is *equivalent* to $(a-12)(b-12)=144$ - just multiply yours by $12ab$, add 144 to both sides and rearrange a little. The advantage of the modified equation is that you can see immediately, that $a-12$ and $b-12$ must be factors of 144.

Comment: Okay, now I can see also, that $\sqrt{(a-12)(b-12)} = 12$ since $\sqrt(144) = 12$ , but what can I do with that ?

Comment: Yes. But there are 8 possible factorisations of 144 into just two factors: $1\cdot144,2\cdot72,\dots,12\cdot12$ and each gives a solution (or in all but the last case two solutions if you count switching $a,b$ as a different solution). For example, from $1\cdot144$ we get $a=1+12=13,b=144+12=156$.

Comment: Oh I see, will PGCD help in those cases ?

Comment: What is PGCD? I cannot figure out what the P might stand for.

Comment: Sorry, I mean GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) , "PGCD is in french...."

Comment: I cannot see how the greatest common divisor is relevant. It is different for each solution.

Comment: Okay, thank's for your help, I'll mark this question as solved .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying through by $12ab$ we get $(a-12)(b-12)=144$.

There are 8 possible factorisations of 144 into two factors: $1\cdot144,2\cdot72,3\cdot48,4\cdot36,6\cdot24,8\cdot18,9\cdot16,12\cdot12$. Those give the solutions as $(a,b)=(13,156),(14,84),(15,60),(16,48),(18,36),(20,30),(21,28),(24,24)$. Obviously the first seven of those can be reversed to give $(a,b)=(156,13)$ etc.

Comment: So there should be at least 30 possible solution by taking into account the negative solutions and their inverse .

Comment: Careful. Negative solutions are a different matter. There we have $(a,b)=(-4,3),(-6,4),(-12,6),(-24,8),(-36,9),(-60,10),(-132,11)$ by a similar method plus another 7 from swapping $a,b$. Sorry, I should have dealt with that.